# How to print unique dict values in list of dicts

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list which look like this:

```
[{'item1': 'random', 'team': 'team1'},
{'item1': 'blabla', 'team': 'team1'},
{'item1': 'xxx', 'team': 'team2'},
{'item1': 'yyy', 'team': 'team2'},
{'item1': 'zzz', 'team': 'team2'}]
```

Now I want to print only the unique teams. In this case `team1` and `team2`. What is an efficient way to do this?

Below will print all teams, not only the unique ones.

```
for item in my_list:
    print(item['team'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can solve your problem,

```
a = [{'item1': 'random', 'team': 'team1'},
{'item1': 'blabla', 'team': 'team1'},
{'item1': 'xxx', 'team': 'team2'},
{'item1': 'yyy', 'team': 'team2'},
{'item1': 'zzz', 'team': 'team2'}]

unique_teams = list(set([i['team'] for i in a]))

print(unique_teams)
```

output:

```
['team1', 'team2']
```

Let me know if this one helps you,please